# Oracle SQL - New row amongst two different id variables with same root variable

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I am trying to combine 4 data sets into one. The tables are linked by a `person id` and `sample id`. Two of those tables have a "specific same ID" field where I would like to create a new row for the each value in `t4.specificsampleid` and leave those blank.  Similarly all `t3` related columns would be blanks/nulls when `t4` is populated.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

| t1.ID | t1.main_spec | t2.ind | t3.specificsampleid | t4.specificsampleid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10R46 | R1005 | y | R1005AB | R1005_st1 |
| 10R46 | R1005 | y | R1005CD | R1005_TB12 |
| 10R46 | R1005 | y | R1005EF | R1005_QZ9 |

IDEAL OUTPUT:

| t1.ID | t1.main_spec | t2.ind | t3.specificsampleid | t4.specificsampleid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10R46 | R1005 | y | R1005AB |  |
| 10R46 | R1005 | y | R1005CD |  |
| 10R46 | R1005 | y | R1005EF |  |
| 10R46 | R1005 | y |  | R1005_st1 |
| 10R46 | R1005 | y |  | R1005_TB12 |
| 10R46 | R1005 | y |  | R1005_QZ9 |

```
'SELECT DISTINCT
demo.[CPDMID],
DEMO.[DFCIMRN],
DEMO.[SampleProcurementDTS],
DEMO.[RecordID],
DEMO.[PathologyAccessionNBR],
DEMO.[TumorTypeDSC],
DEMO.[PatientTreatmentHistoryDSC],
DEMO.[TissueSiteOfTumorSampleDSC],
DEMO.[OtherTissueSiteOfTumorSampleTXT],
DEMO.[TissueSiteOfPrimaryCancerDSC],
DEMO.[TopLineDiagnosisFromPathologistTXT],
DEMO.[SummarizedDiagnosisTXT],
--cryo data section---------
CRYO.[CPDMIDBloodAvailabilityTXT] CryoCpdmidBloodAvailabilityTXT,
CRYO.[CryopreservedCellsFLG] CryopreservedCellsIND,
--pdcl data section-----------
pdcl.[PDCLID],
PDCL.[MediaTypeDSC] PdclMediaTypeDSC,
PDCL.[CultureSubstrateDSC] PdclCultureSubstrateDSC,
PDCL.[SixMonthUpdateFinalStatusCD] PdclSixMonthUpdateFinalStatCD, 
PDCL.[GrowthVerifiedFLG] PdclGrowthVerifiedIND,
--dummy pdx columns for union 

NULL AS "PdxAttemptID",
NULL AS "PdxStrainOfMouseCD",
NULL AS "PdxTumorLocationCD",
NULL AS "PdxTumorGrowthIND",
NULL AS "PdxSixMonthFinalStatusCD"
DEMO.[LastLoadDTS]

FROM 

[SAM].[CPDM].PatientDemographicsPathology demo 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
([SAM].[CPDM].[LiveCryoPatientCells] cryo INNER JOIN [SAM].[CPDM]. 
[PatientDerivedCellLines] pdcl on CRYO.[CPDMID] = PDCL.[CPDMID] AND 
CRYO.DFCIMRN = PDCL.DFCIMRN)
ON DEMO.CPDMID = CRYO.CPDMID AND DEMO.DFCIMRN = CRYO.DFCIMRN

union 
--THIS PORTION GRABS ALL PDX DATA AND CREATES DUMMY COLUMNS FOR THE 
PDCL, ALLOWING THE UNION
select DISTINCT
demo.[CPDMID],
DEMO.[DFCIMRN],
DEMO.[SampleProcurementDTS],
DEMO.[RecordID],
DEMO.[PathologyAccessionNBR],
dEMO.[TumorTypeDSC],
DEMO.[PatientTreatmentHistoryDSC],
DEMO.[TissueSiteOfTumorSampleDSC],
DEMO.[OtherTissueSiteOfTumorSampleTXT],
DEMO.[TissueSiteOfPrimaryCancerDSC],
DEMO.[TopLineDiagnosisFromPathologistTXT],
DEMO.[SummarizedDiagnosisTXT],
--cryo data section---------
CRYO.[CPDMIDBloodAvailabilityTXT] CryoCpdmidBloodAvailabilityTXT,
CRYO.[CryopreservedCellsFLG] CryopreservedCellsIND,
--pdcl data section-----------
--dumy cell line columns
NULL AS "PDCLID",
NULL AS "PdclMediaTypeDSC",
NULL AS "PdclCultureSubstrateDSC",
NULL AS "PdclSixMonthUpdateFinalStatCD",
NULL AS "PdclGrowthVerifiedIND",
--pdx data section

--pdx.[PDXAttemptedFLG] PdxAttemptedIND,
pdx.[PDXAttemptID] PdxAttemptID,
pdx.[StrainofMouseCD] PdxStrainOfMouseCD ,
pdx.[TumorLocationCD] PdxTumorLocationCD,
pdx.[TumourGrowthFLG] PdxTumorGrowthIND,
pdx.[SixMonthUpdateFinalStatusCD] PdxSixMonthFinalStatusCD
DEMO.[LastLoadDTS]

FROM 
[SAM].[CPDM].PatientDemographicsPathology demo 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
([SAM].[CPDM].[LiveCryoPatientCells] cryo INNER JOIN [SAM].[CPDM]. 
[PatientDerivedXenografts] PDX on CRYO.[CPDMID] = PDX.[CPDMID] AND 
CRYO.DFCIMRN = PDX.DFCIMRN)
ON DEMO.CPDMID = CRYO.CPDMID AND DEMO.DFCIMRN = CRYO.DFCIMRN'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you would provide the input table definitions and not just the expected output, but if I'm understanding correctly, I think you might just want to use a `UNION ALL`.

Something like:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.main_spec, t2.ind, t3.specificsampleid t3ssid, null t4ssid
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2
  ON [Condition]
 INNER JOIN t3
  ON [Condition]
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.ID, t1.main_spec, t2.ind, null t3ssid, t4.specificsampleid t4ssid
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2
  ON [Condition]
 INNER JOIN t4
  ON [Condition]
```

The first part will get all the rows with a match on t3 (and put null in the relevant t4 column), the second part will get all the rows with a match on t4 (and put null in the relevant t3 column), and the `UNION ALL` will combine them.

In other words, it will get two rows if there is a match in t3 and t4, or one row if there is only a match in one.

If you need rows where there is a match in neither t3 nor t4, you could add a third part after another `UNION ALL` or edit one of the existing parts to handle that case.

I'm sure there are alternatives, but I hope this is a good starting point for your problem.

**Edited** to add a version that also returns a row when there is a match in neither t3 nor t4 (as mentioned above, there are multiple ways of doing this):

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.main_spec, t2.ind, t3.specificsampleid t3ssid, null t4ssid
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2
  ON [Condition]
 INNER JOIN t3
  ON [Condition]
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.ID, t1.main_spec, t2.ind, null t3ssid, t4.specificsampleid t4ssid
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2
  ON [Condition]
 INNER JOIN t4
  ON [Condition]
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.ID, t1.main_spec, t2.ind, t3.specificsampleid t3ssid, t4.specificsampleid t4ssid
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2
  ON [Condition]
LEFT OUTER JOIN t3
  ON [Condition]
LEFT OUTER JOIN t4
  ON [Condition]
WHERE t3.primarykey IS NULL AND t4.primarykey IS NULL
```

Comment: One follow up question @EdmCoff, how do I prevent the union from creating a row where you have t1 and t2 variables not null but all variables from t3 and t4 return in this same row all nulls.

Comment: @Brad If I'm understanding correctly, you could simply add that as a condition. In the query before the `union`, you could end with `WHERE t3.ssid IS NOT NULL` and at the end of the query you could end with `WHERE t4.ssid IS NOT NULL`.  If your actual example is for multiple columns, you can `OR` them together like `WHERE t4.c1 IS NOT NULL OR t4.c2 IS NOT NULL OR...`

Comment: First thanks for the response, when I add a where clause to each of the 2 queries involved it still returns rows where all t3 and t4 variables are null (which I am trying to not include).  I've tried wrapping the whole thing in a sub query and at the end adding a 'where t3ssid is not null and t4ssid is not null' and that returns nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't work if you added it individually (please share the exact code), but your condition for wrapping the whole thing is wrong... it should be `OR`, not `AND`.

Comment: @Edm_Coff please see the updated description, I don't know how to add a file or if it is possible so I just included the whole query as it is currently.  Also, there may be instances where pdx or pdcl variables should be null.  But if there is IDs populated in either or both of those tables there should never be subsequent record for that ID where pdx and pdcl variables are all nulls

Comment: I think this should probably be raised as a new question. If a non-null `PDCL.[CPDMID]` and non-null `PDX.[CPDMID]` are all you care about, I think your `ON` conditions should probably handle it already. Or do you mean something else by `id`?

Comment: So we want everything from the DEMO table.  The cpdmid and dfcimrn are keys to the other 3 tables. Each CPDMID has one corresponding match in cryo table, and may have one or match in PDCL and/or PDX or zero and only match back to cryo.  So what we want is if there is a value in pdclid or pdxattemptid (this is an extended version of the CPDM id - for instance demo.cpdmid = 123x could have pdcl.pdclid = 123x_pdcl and/or pdx.pdxattemptid =123x_pdx) those should be populated on a new row for each.

Comment: What we don't want is if either or both of those are populated to have a row for the demo.CPDMID where columns from pdx and pdcl are all null (so in the current query and above example there would be three rows for 123x - 1) with all demo and and cryo and nulls in pdcl and pdx columns (this is what I am trying to remove) 2) one row for the pdclid 123x_pdcl with pdcl variables filled and pdx variables null, and 3) one row for 123x_pdcl that follows the opposite of number 2.

Comment: Subsequently, if a CPDMID has nothing in either PDX or PDCL , would want just its cryo results and in this situation acceptable to have pdx and pdcl variables all null.

Comment: I have added an additional example that I think does what you're describing (with an additional `UNION ALL`). Since the first and second part use `INNER JOIN`s, they will only return rows when there is match. The third part will exclusively return rows where there is no match. It's likely possible to do this with only two parts to the `union` as you're trying, but I think this is simpler since I don't know your actual data or join logic.

Comment: Thanks I think this should work but realized the data I am working is bad which is leading to this scenario.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The WITH clause is here just for sample data generation and, as such, it is not the part of the answer.

I assume that the first table in your question is a result that you already have (as a view maybe) and that this resulting dataset is starting point to get the expected result.
Using just a union with crossed where conditions

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select '10R46' "T1_ID", 'R1005' "T1_MAIN_SPEC", 'Y' "T2_IND", 'R1005AB' "T3_SPEC_ID", 'R1005_ST1' "T4_SPEC_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select '10R46' "T1_ID", 'R1005' "T1_MAIN_SPEC", 'Y' "T2_IND", 'R1005CD' "T3_SPEC_ID", 'R1005_TB12' "T4_SPEC_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select '10R46' "T1_ID", 'R1005' "T1_MAIN_SPEC", 'Y' "T2_IND", 'R1005EF' "T3_SPEC_ID", 'R1005_QZ9' "T4_SPEC_ID" From Dual
        )
SELECT 
    T1_ID "T1_ID", T1_MAIN_SPEC "T1_MAIN_SPEC", T2_IND "T2_IND", T3_SPEC_ID "T3_SPEC_ID", null "T4_SPEC_ID"
FROM 
    tbl  
WHERE
    T3_SPEC_ID Is Not Null
UNION ALL    
SELECT  
    T1_ID "T1_ID", T1_MAIN_SPEC "T1_MAIN_SPEC", T2_IND "T2_IND", Null "T3_SPEC_ID", T4_SPEC_ID "T4_SPEC_ID"
FROM 
    tbl  
WHERE 
    T4_SPEC_ID Is Not Null
--  
--  R e s u l t
--  
--  T1_ID T1_MAIN_SPEC T2_IND T3_SPEC_ID T4_SPEC_ID
--  ----- ------------ ------ ---------- ----------
--  10R46 R1005        Y      R1005AB               
--  10R46 R1005        Y      R1005CD               
--  10R46 R1005        Y      R1005EF               
--  10R46 R1005        Y                 R1005_ST1  
--  10R46 R1005        Y                 R1005_TB12 
--  10R46 R1005        Y                 R1005_QZ9
```

Using full outer join and some data transformation - here is the SQL and result.

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select '10R46' "T1_ID", 'R1005' "T1_MAIN_SPEC", 'Y' "T2_IND", 'R1005AB' "T3_SPEC_ID", 'R1005_ST1' "T4_SPEC_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select '10R46' "T1_ID", 'R1005' "T1_MAIN_SPEC", 'Y' "T2_IND", 'R1005CD' "T3_SPEC_ID", 'R1005_TB12' "T4_SPEC_ID" From Dual Union All
            Select '10R46' "T1_ID", 'R1005' "T1_MAIN_SPEC", 'Y' "T2_IND", 'R1005EF' "T3_SPEC_ID", 'R1005_QZ9' "T4_SPEC_ID" From Dual
        )
SELECT DISTINCT
    T1_ID,
    T1_MAIN_SPEC,
    T2_IND,
    CASE WHEN B_T3_SPEC_ID Is Null And B_T4_SPEC_ID Is Null THEN T3_SPEC_ID ELSE Null END "T3_SPEC_ID",
    CASE 
        WHEN CASE WHEN B_T3_SPEC_ID Is Null And B_T4_SPEC_ID Is Null THEN T3_SPEC_ID ELSE Null END Is Null 
        THEN T4_SPEC_ID 
    ELSE Null
    END "T4_SPEC_ID"
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
             a.T1_ID, a.T1_MAIN_SPEC, a.T2_IND, 
             a.T3_SPEC_ID, 
             a.T4_SPEC_ID,
             CASE WHEN a.T4_SPEC_ID = b.T4_SPEC_ID THEN b.T3_SPEC_ID ELSE Null END "B_T3_SPEC_ID", 
             CASE WHEN a.T3_SPEC_ID <> b.T3_SPEC_ID THEN Null ELSE b.T4_SPEC_ID END "B_T4_SPEC_ID"
        FROM
            tbl a
        FULL OUTER JOIN
            tbl b ON (b.T1_ID = a.T1_ID And b.T1_MAIN_SPEC = a.T1_MAIN_SPEC And b.T2_IND = a.T2_IND)
    )
ORDER BY
    T1_ID,
    T1_MAIN_SPEC,
    T2_IND
--  
--  R e s u l t
--  
--  T1_ID T1_MAIN_SPEC T2_IND T3_SPEC_ID T4_SPEC_ID
--  ----- ------------ ------ ---------- ----------
--  10R46 R1005        Y      R1005AB               
--  10R46 R1005        Y      R1005CD               
--  10R46 R1005        Y      R1005EF               
--  10R46 R1005        Y                 R1005_QZ9  
--  10R46 R1005        Y                 R1005_ST1  
--  10R46 R1005        Y                 R1005_TB12
```

Regards...